# Using WebClient to login to Pinterest (403 Error)

Tags: c#, webclient, http-status-code-403

So I'm trying to login to Pinterest using a WebClient in an ASP.NET page.  This is the CookieWebAwareClient I am currently using:

```
public class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
{
    public CookieAwareWebClient()
        : this(new CookieContainer())
    { }

    public CookieAwareWebClient(CookieContainer c)
    {
        this.CookieContainer = c;
        this.Headers.Add("User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.52 Safari/536.5");
    }

    public CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; set; }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        if (request is HttpWebRequest)
        {
            (request as HttpWebRequest).CookieContainer = this.CookieContainer;
        }
        return request;
    }
}
```

Here is the code I am using to login, first doing a GET request to get the csrf token and the other _ch value they use.

```
var client = new CookieAwareWebClient();
client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

string html = client.DownloadString("https://pinterest.com/login/");

string csrftoken = GetCSRFToken(html);
string chtoken = GetCHToken(html);

var values = new NameValueCollection();
values.Add("email", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(MY_EMAIL));
values.Add("password",MY_PASSWORD);
values.Add("csrfmiddlewaretoken", csrftoken);
values.Add("_ch", chtoken);

// 403 Error happens below
client.UploadValues("https://pinterest.com/login/?next=%2Flogin%2F", values);

html = client.DownloadString("http://pinterest.com/settings");
```

I feel like I'm just missing something small but can't determine what it is.

Comment: you seem to be making a web request over ssl but not do any ssl based handshake/authentication beforehand; 403 error indicates that you have made a connection to the web server but the server refuses to handle further requests and closes it ("forbidden")...

Comment: why this question is tagged `django`?

Comment: @user - the token are missing while loggin in!

Comment: It was marked django because it was accessing a csrfmiddlewaretoken, wasn't sure if that would provide further insight or not.